# vue js default values before data comes in

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

https://codepen.io/oxy1023/pen/qBKXdEQ
Here is the full code.

hello. I am showing the data received through node-red on the screen.

The problem is that the screen disappears when no data comes in. It asks me to specify a default value, but I don't know what to do.

I tried putting null or " " but it doesn't work. Which part of my code is wrong?

```
mounted() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      document.getElementById(`v${i}`).style.backgroundColor = "none";
      this.arr[i].device_name = null;
      this.arr[i].manufac_predict_time = null;
      this.arr[i].cnc_status = null;
      this.arr[i].alarm_status = null;
      this.arr[i].comm_status = null;
  }
},
```

Comment: ```arr: this.$store.state.mqtt_data_arr || []``` You mean this ??

Comment: @DipakTelangre The syntax seems correct. But it doesn't work. It only works when data actually comes in from node-red.

Comment: I don't exactly understand the problem but the way you assign value in `mounted()` will **sometimes** not work and will only work if you use `$set()` like here: https://codepen.io/captainskippah/pen/qBKPBob. Docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays